# Temporarily Disable back button

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

In my program, I have a async task that is executed when navigating TO a page. Problem is,  when I navigate away from that task (using the hardware back button of the phone) The task is not yet finished and the app crashes. So my question is, how can I temporarily disable the back button. This so I can re-enable it when the async task has finnished?

Thanks,

Bart Teunissen

Comment: Is it only when people navigate away from the page using the back button or also when navigating away using for example the Home button are click on a push notification? If your app crashes also when navigating away using the other methods disabling the back button is no solution

Comment: It does not crash when navigating away using the home button, cause then all tasks are probably ended anyways. So the problem purely lies in the back button navigation.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend fixing the crash, rather than disabling the back button (how does your app cope if they press the start button, or receive a phone call instead?)

Comment: Preventing the use of the back button in this situation is addressing the sympton and not the cause. Doing so may also affect your ability to pass marketplace certification due to "breaking" the standard back button behaviour.

Comment: I'm making a proof of concept for my final assignment for my school. The bug is the only bug left, and i dont have time to make a shiny solution or to re-write large parts of code. Thats why im aiming at the sympton and not the cause. The app just needs to hold up on my presentation, so i can graduate. This also anwsers the question about the windows phone market. It doesn't need the certificate. The phone i use to demonstrate my concept, does not have a sim card installed, so the user being called is out of the question. I dont have a lot of time left before i need to demonstrate my concept..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion i think that you should in as many cases as possible try to have the back button enabled, just because there are a back button because you should be able to back (makes sence). But if you would like to know how you could do it here is an way:
You could just initialize the OnBackKeyPress method and use an boolean to define if the async-task has been finished or not. Define the variable BusyWithAsync and put it to true when the async-task starts and once it is completed just put BusyWithAsync variable to false and you should be ready to go.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (BusyWithAsync)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```